# Gnuplot: unset variable

Tags: gnuplot

Quite a basic question, I guess, but neither Google nor the docs helped me much so: **is it possible to undefine variables?** So that

```
a = 0
[some operation]
print(exists("a"))
```

results in `0` being printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`undefine`](http://www.bersch.net/gnuplot-doc/undefine.html):

```
gnuplot> print a           
         undefined variable: a

gnuplot> print(exists("a"))
0
gnuplot> a=10
gnuplot> print a           
10
gnuplot> print(exists("a"))
1
gnuplot> undefine a
gnuplot> print a           
         undefined variable: a

gnuplot> print(exists("a"))
0
gnuplot>
```